# Display session variable as selected in the dropdown of another page

Tags: php

I have set a value in a session variable in 1 page, now I have to display that session variable value on another page's dropdown as selected.
I've tried everything but couldn't get it to work, maybe because of bad coding.

Here is my code:

```
<select name="subject_id" 
  class="select-form subjectSelect sub" onchange="ajaxDrp(this.value)" 
 >
    <option value="" style="color:#000">Select</option>
    <?php
    $sql = "select * from mock_subject ";
    $res = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
    $numrows =mysqli_num_rows($res);
    echo mysql_error();

    if($numrows){
      while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
        if($obj->status == 1){
          if($subjectId == $obj->id){ 
            echo '<option  value="'.obj->id.'" 
                    style="color:#000" 
                    selected >'.$obj-    >subject_name.'
                  </option>';
          } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$obj->id.'" 
                    style="color:#000">'.($obj->subject_name).'
                  </option>';   
          }
        }
      }   
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Session is already started, my session variable value is `subject'Id`, but in the dropdown I have to display `subjectId`'s subject name, and code is like this code session:

```
$_SESSION["subject"] = "contains subject ID"
```

Comment: NOTE: I have removed an apostrophe `'` from the start and end of your code block, as it was stopping the syntax highlighter working. I presumed this was an attempt at formatting code. If this was part of your actual code add it back

Comment: specify correct syntax, what you want to display in your output.

Comment: i have specified , i want to display subject's name in the output.